# Append extension output to main content via typoscript

Tags: plugins, typoscript, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

It might be a simple solution to that but I am not able to figure it out.

I implement a `typo3 6.2.12` website using the `bootstrap_package` extension. There I have a page with child pages within the page tree. On each child page a comment function should be attached at the end of the main page content. For the comment functionality I use the `pw_comments` extension, as it is very flexible.

The `pw_comments` manual shows a possible the integration as follows:

```
lib.content = COA
lib.content {
  10 < styles.content.get

  # List comments
  20 < lib.pwCommentsIndex

  # Write new comment
  30 < lib.pwCommentsNew
}
```

Actually very simple and straightforward.

The bootstrap package extension handles the content as follows (inside base.ts):

```
lib.dynamicContent = COA
lib.dynamicContent {
    5 = LOAD_REGISTER
    5 {
        colPos.cObject = TEXT
        colPos.cObject {
            field = colPos
            ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
            ifEmpty.cObject {
                value.current = 1
                ifEmpty = 0
            }
        }

        pageUid.cObject = TEXT
        pageUid.cObject {
            field = pageUid
            ifEmpty.data = TSFE:id
        }
    }

    20 < styles.content.get
    20.select.where = colPos={register:colPos}
    20.select.where.insertData = 1
    20.select.pidInList.data = register:pageUid

    90 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}

lib.dynamicContentSlide =< lib.dynamicContent
lib.dynamicContentSlide.20.slide = -1
```

And at that point I have no clue how to integrate `pw_comments`. In the setup of the plugin I tried this:

```
[PIDupinRootline = 54]
    lib.dynamicContent = COA
    lib.dynamicContent {
        # List comments
        30 < lib.pwCommentsIndex

        # Write new comment
        31 < lib.pwCommentsNew
    }
[end]
```

The goal of the above is: Attach `pw_comments` to the main column output to each child page of parent page with uid 54.

Actually it is working but due to the inheritance with `lib.dynamicContentSlide =< lib.dynamicContent` the comments get also attached each of the 3 footer columns which is not desired behavior.

I could use the plugin extension which is available for `pw_comments` but that would mean that the editor has always to add that plugin to new child pages when creating them.
I could "hack" the fluid content template files and add a `<f:cObject />` tag and call the plugin lib, but I think that solution is odd and .. well .. a hack.

So is there any way how I could attach that plugin to these child pages in a typo script way? I guess it is just a lack of syntax knowledge and yes, typo3 is not my every day job.

Hope anybody can give me a hand on this issue. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You simple need to replace the reference by a real copy before you add your `TypoScript`.

```
lib.dynamicContentSlide < lib.dynamicContent
# your TS goes here
```

Just repeat all lines with an reference to `lib.dynamicContent` with a copy operator instead, before you add your modifications to the actual content definition.